# How to disable loop on embeded video from vimeo

Tags: javascript, embed, vimeo, vimeo-player

I'm trying to perform an action on the 'ended' event on my embeded vimeo clip. This is not firing because, according to vimeo documentation, video is on loop. So I tried adding `loop=0` to the url but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
<body>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/717499153?muted=1&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=0" width="240" height="320" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" title="video" data-ready="true"></iframe>
</body>
```

Is that some sort of rule for autoplayed embeds? How can I force it to play just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add also background=1 as documented here :

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos

background - false -

For videos on a Vimeo Plus account or higher: whether to hide all video controls, loop the video automatically, enable autoplay, and mute the video. The loop and autoplay behaviors can't be overridden, but the mute behavior can be; see the muted argument below.

This is the correct URL :

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/717499153?muted=1&controls=0&autoplay=1&background=1&loop=0" width="240" height="320" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" title="video" data-ready="true"></iframe>
```

I do recommend next time to contact Vimeo Support to help with this,

Have a nice day